# Converting nvarchar to bigint in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert `nvarchar(16)` to `bigint` but receives an error as follows

```
"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."
```

How can I fix it this is my sp

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[GenerateAccountNo]

As 

Begin
declare @tmp bigint
set @tmp =(CONVERT(bigint,'1111111111111111'))
return @tmp

End
```

And call procedure

```
DECLARE @returnvalue bigint

 EXEC @returnvalue = GenerateAccountNo

 select @returnvalue
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the part that's causing the error? This works with me. It also works on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21136

Comment: yes I'm sure it doesnt work

Comment: What data are you putting in when it fails?

Comment: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GenerateAccountNo, Line 18
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
The 'GenerateAccountNo' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from a stored proc is INT, not BIGINT. Stored procs are designed for data selection. You should use a FUNCTION in this case instead to return a scalar value that is not related to a table.

Comment: Thank u Lukos u are right. I must use select not return.When calling the sp in c# code I have to use parameterdirection=output.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

> Return a status value to a calling procedure or batch to indicate success or failure (and the reason for failure).

You are returning the status(`INT`) from a Stored Procedure. This would be the execution result code (success or failure). If you want to return results from a Stored Procedure just use `SELECT` within the SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateAccountNo]
As 
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,'1111111111111111')
END
```

Comment: But when we use select we can't call sp from the c# code

Comment: @erhanurun Well, at least the problem you asked initially is resolved now: you cannot return anything other than an `int` from a stored procedure using the `RETURN` statement. I suggest you ask a new question about how to obtain a `bigint` value from a stored procedure calling it from C# code. Or maybe try searching for a ready answer – it might well exist already!

Comment: @AndriyM I agree with creating a new question for a separate problem. I also think the assumption of not being able to get results from SP within C# is wrong as you can see an example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37hwc7kt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I haven't written C# in a LONG time, but can't you use output parameters as shown below? That said, a user defined function as suggested by Lukos might be a better option depending on the actual code you need in your method.

```
create procedure [dbo].[generateaccountno] @account_number [bigint] = null output
as
  begin
      set @account_number =( convert(bigint, '1111111111111111') );
  end;
go
declare @account_number [bigint];
execute [dbo].[generateaccountno] @account_number = @account_number output;
select @account_number as [@account_number];
```

Comment: Yeah, you should never use rerturn for anything except to see if there was an error. Output parameters make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

thank u for your answers. I fix the problem as follows...

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[GenerateAccountNo]

  As 
    Begin
    declare @tmp bigint
    set @tmp =(CONVERT(bigint,'1111111111111111'))
    select @tmp

    End
```

and calling the procedure as follows...

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GenerateAccountNo", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@accountNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar,16);
            parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```